# Total War Three Kingdoms: What are the exact figures on corruption?

Tags: three-kingdoms-total-war

Corruption is a major issue in total war three kingdoms and I have not been able to find exact figures on how corruption percentages are calculated.

1. Does each additional settlement cause more corruption or is it by each
   new commandery you gain settlements in?
2. If so then by how much? How much does each settlement/commandery add?
3. Does corruption scale exponentially? Will your 20th commandery add more corruption than your 5th?
4. What is the exact number of settlements/commanderies that starts to cause corruption?
5. How much can you reduce corruption by giving away settlements/commanderies through region trading?
6. How does you prestige level effect corruption for factions that don't have corruption reductions build into their campaign (like Ma Teng)?
7. How does the distance to your capital effect corruption?

FYI I am not looking for information on how to reduce corruption only what causes it to optimize the use of techniques to reduce it.

Comment: One major factor that isn't mentioned is your capital. The distance between your capital and your settlements has a huge effect on corruption, making the answers to 1-5 "it depends"

Comment: Oh wow, thanks I haven't seen that one before! I'll add it to the list.